# confused if this question be asked here or in ELL

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I get confused where to ask questions, here or on English Language Learners. Anyway,  could ["What is the term of someone who like to have the center of attention, talks about him self and greatness"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/60866/what-is-the-term-of-someone-who-like-to-have-the-center-of-attention-talks-about)
 be asked here?

Comment: There are a few errors in the title, it should be: What is the term **for** someone who **likes to be** the center of attention, **by talking** about **himself** and **his accomplishments**"**?**"

Comment: As [Jeff Atwood](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/91/jeff-atwood) explains in [this SE blog post](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/), single-word-requests aren't generally welcomed by SE itself (guessing game, beauty contest, lazy man's thesaurus). But most *users* like them (probably because nearly everyone can chip in with something, even if only as a comment). But I doubt they're usually very relevant to actually learning how to use English, so if they must go somewhere, they're probably better on ELU than ELL (with fixed titles, obviously! :)

Comment: The best place to ask these questions is to your friends in real life!